# How to accept connections for ipython from other computers?

Tags: configuration, ipython

I run ipython 0.12.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. You can run it in browser using notebook interface by running:

```
ipython notebook --pylab
```

Configuration files can be found in `~/.config/ipython/profile_default/`. It seems that connection parameters for every kernel is placed in `~/.config/ipython/profile_default/security/kernel-4e424cf4-ba44-441a-824c-c6bce727e585.json`. Here is the content of this file (new files are created as you start new kernels):

```
{
  "stdin_port": 54204, 
  "ip": "127.0.0.1", 
  "hb_port": 58090, 
  "key": "2a105dd9-26c5-40c6-901f-a72254d59876", 
  "shell_port": 52155, 
  "iopub_port": 42228
}
```

It's rather self-explanatory but how can I set a server that would have a permanent configuration, so I can use notebook interface from other computers in the LAN?

Comment: Do you want to use the *notebook* from other computers on the LAN, or use the kernels directly (e.g. open a QtConsole to share the kernel of an existing notebook, etc.)?  The answer is different.

Comment: @minrk I want run the server to which I can connect with browser from another computer in the LAN and have notebook interface, as if I run the command ipython notebook --pylab locally, but in this case I'd have to write an address of another computer in the lan, for example http://myserver:8888 instead of http://127.0.0.1:8888

Comment: In that case, the kernel connection files are not relevant to you (they are how the notebook server talks to the kernels).  Answer coming...

Answer (score 114, accepted):

If you are using an old version of the notebook, the following could still apply. For new versions see the other answers below.

---

[Relevant section of the IPython docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/notebook/public_server.html#running-a-public-notebook-server)

The Notebook server listens on localhost by default.  If you want it to be visible to all machines on your LAN, simply instruct it to listen on all interfaces:

```
ipython notebook --ip='*'
```

Or a specific IP visible to other machines:

```
ipython notebook --ip=192.168.0.123
```

Depending on your environment, it is probably a good idea to [enable HTTPS and a password](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/htmlnotebook.html#security) when listening on external interfaces.

If you plan on serving publicly a lot, then it's a also good idea to create an IPython profile (e.g. `ipython profile create nbserver`) and edit the config accordingly, so all you need to do is:

```
ipython notebook --profile nbserver
```

To load all your ip/port/ssl/password settings.

Comment: And you can disable password request with `--NotebookApp.token=''` (possibly unsafe): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41159797/how-to-disable-password-request-for-a-jupyter-notebook-session/47509274#47509274

Answer (score 21):

#### The accepted answer/information is for an old version. How to enable remote access to your new jupyter notebook? I got you covered

First, generate a config file if you don't have it already:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

Notice the output of this command as it would tell you where the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file was generated. Or if you already have it, it will ask you if you would like to overwrite it with the default config. Edit the following line:

```
## The IP address the notebook server will listen on.
c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0' # Any ip
```

For added security, type in a python/IPython shell:

```
from notebook.auth import passwd; passwd()
```

You will be asked to input and confirm a password string. Copy the contents of the string, which should be of the form type:salt:hashed-password. Find and edit the lines as follows:

```
## Hashed password to use for web authentication.
#  
#  To generate, type in a python/IPython shell:
#  
#    from notebook.auth import passwd; passwd()
#  
#  The string should be of the form type:salt:hashed-password.
c.NotebookApp.password = 'type:salt:the-hashed-password-you-have-generated'

## Forces users to use a password for the Notebook server. This is useful in a
#  multi user environment, for instance when everybody in the LAN can access each
#  other's machine through ssh.
#  
#  In such a case, server the notebook server on localhost is not secure since
#  any user can connect to the notebook server via ssh.
c.NotebookApp.password_required = True

## Set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header
#  
#  Use '*' to allow any origin to access your server.
#  
#  Takes precedence over allow_origin_pat.
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*'
```

(Re)start your jupyter notebook, voila!

Comment: As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43500232/588437), I needed `c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*'` as well.

Comment: @ijoseph thank you for your contribution, added allow_origin to the answer!