# Use ein (emacs ipython notebook) on remote server

Tags: python, emacs, ipython, remote-access

I have installed and configured *ein* (emacs ipython notebook) to work on my local linux/mac machines. However, I would like to use ein to open ipython notebooks on a remote server and run them from within ein. Is this possible and if so could someone tell me how can this be done?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: No. I have not yet resolved the issue

Comment: What do you think about setting up emacs and ein on the same server running the ipython notebook, and just ssh to it from your local machine using `ssh -X`?

Answer (score 3):

```
M-x ein:notebooklist-open <enter>
```

ein prompts back with

```
URL or port number (default 8888):
```

At this point enter the full HTTP-URL of where ipython-server is running e.g.

```
http://192.168.1.7:8888
```

(On the ipython server side -- by default it runs only on localhost:8888 .  You should have started it with something like:

```
ipython notebook --ip="*"
```

).  For e.g. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538846/how-to-accept-connections-for-ipython-from-other-computers).

Comment: That's actually not the problem. The problem is, that ein seems to loose connection immediately after opening a notebook. At least for me that was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with ein disconnecting immediately.

I solved it by creating a SSH tunnel from port 8888 on my local machine to port 8888 on the remote machine. Then, when ein asks where to connect just accept the default localhost:8888.

I then needed to, as I recall, tell the notebook server to [bind on all IP addresses](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#notebook-public-server) (not just localhost). There are some potential security concerns with that, so make sure that you've got authentication and/or a proper firewall set up.

Comment: The link added here is dead so I just want to put in what ended up working for me, https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/jupyter-notebooks/remote-jupyter-notebook/