# How to disable password request for a Jupyter notebook session?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, python-3.5, jupyter

I have been launching Jupyter Notebook for years using the following command:

```
jupyter-notebook --port=7000 --no-browser --no-mathjax
```

When I try to open the jupyter on the browser it ask me for a password, even though I have never set any before.
It is important to note that If I do set the port to a value different than `7000 (eg., the default 8888)` the interface will open with no problem

**I am running jupyter locally, and on the following setup:**

```
Python 3.5.2
```

**With the following modules installed:**

```
jupyter (1.0.0), jupyter-client (4.4.0), jupyter-console (5.0.0), jupyter-core (4.2.1), ipykernel (4.5.2), ipython (5.1.0), ipython-genutils (0.1.0), nbconvert (4.3.0), nbformat (4.2.0), notebook (4.3.0)
```

**NOTE: I have no jupyter configurations file**

Following are some of the output lines from the server:

```
[I 19:16:24.358 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/my_user_name
[I 19:16:24.358 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 19:16:24.358 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:7000/?token=aa0dab6e2d85766f3e2e4f0f6633e4473db56a56c94cac76
[I 19:16:24.358 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

And follwing are messages after I try to open it on the browser (using port 7000)

```
[I 19:21:56.848 NotebookApp] 302 GET /tree (::1) 8.46ms
[D 19:21:56.857 NotebookApp] Using contents: services/contents
[D 19:21:56.919 NotebookApp] Path base/images/favicon.ico served from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/static/base/images/favicon.ico
[D 19:21:56.920 NotebookApp] Path components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css served from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/static/components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css
[D 19:21:56.922 NotebookApp] Path components/jquery-typeahead/dist/jquery.typeahead.min.css served from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/static/components/jquery-typeahead/dist/jquery.typeahead.min.css
[D 19:21:56.923 NotebookApp] Path style/style.min.css served from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/static/style/style.min.css
[D 19:21:56.925 NotebookApp] Path auth/css/override.css served from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/static/auth/css/override.css
[D 19:21:56.926 NotebookApp] Path components/es6-promise/promise.min.js served from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/static/components/es6-promise/promise.min.js
[D 19:21:56.926 NotebookApp] Path components/requirejs/require.js served from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/static/components/requirejs/require.js
[D 19:21:56.933 NotebookApp] Path base/images/logo.png served from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/static/base/images/logo.png
[D 19:21:56.934 NotebookApp] 200 GET /login?next=%2Ftree (::1) 80.86ms
[D 19:21:57.001 NotebookApp] Path custom.css served from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/static/custom/custom.css
[D 19:21:57.003 NotebookApp] 304 GET /custom/custom.css (::1) 3.11ms
[D 19:21:57.341 NotebookApp] Path auth/js/main.min.js served from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/static/auth/js/main.min.js
[D 19:21:57.344 NotebookApp] 200 GET /static/auth/js/main.min.js?v=20161219191623 (::1) 3.57ms
```

At this point there is a page from jupyter asking me to insert a password I have never set before.

### SOLVED!

With latest update of notebook module (4.3.1) the problem has been solved.

Once the jupyter notebook is launched the user is prompted to paste a URL into the browser at the first connection:

```
Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
    http://localhost:7000/?token=32be0f5ee74cfe521187bc479855ce8b9fbab9e8021701c9
```

This solved the problem!

Comment: Does the same happen if you don't run Jupyter? Which messages does Jupyter print to stdout?

Comment: Yes! These are some of the last output lines (removed starting part in square brackets):


Path base/images/logo.png served from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/static/base/images/logo.png
200 GET /login?next=%2Ftree (::1) 106.60ms


Path custom.css served from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/static/custom/custom.css
304 GET /custom/custom.css (::1) 3.09ms


Path auth/js/main.min.js served from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/static/auth/js/main.min.js
200 GET /static/auth/js/main.min.js?v=20161215192744 (::1) 4.07ms

Comment: I think some other program is running on port 7000 instead. The *last* output lines aren't so interesting here; if the port is taken, you should see it somewhere in the *first* output lines. Please edit your question (rather than commenting) to include the output of the `jupyter-notebook` command.

Comment: "*SOLVED!*", more accurately: bypassed, not fixed. It seems everything running Python in a browser should have this kind of "security". Fixing it would need not to use a browser, so maybe a bad design choice in the first place. More answers from the [Jupyter team](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2254) in 2019 which mentions an environment variable `JUPYTER_TOKEN`, another bypass.

Answer (score 123):

The following is very unsafe, but you can remove the password completely with:

```
jupyter notebook --ip='*' --NotebookApp.token='' --NotebookApp.password=''
```

Without `--NotebookApp.password=''`, when connecting from a remote computer to a local Jupyter launched simply with:

```
jupyter notebook --ip='*'
```

it still asks for a password for security reasons, since users with access can run arbitrary Python code on the server machine!

Note that on my machine, running just:

```
jupyter notebook
```

already opens a logged-in window on my browser, and stdout contains:

```
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/ciro/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-3286-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=7c9265bf9df5f57cf5da88f410a71b097e2548ae375826b7
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=7c9265bf9df5f57cf5da88f410a71b097e2548ae375826b7
```

so if your browser is not opening automatically, you can try one of those links, which seem to have a login token on them, and then investigate why your browser is not opening automatically.

Tested on Jupyter 4.4.x, Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: This throws an error behind the proxy `'_xsrf' argument missing from POST`

Comment: "*The following is very unsafe, but you can remove the password completely*", if it is very unsafe, why mentioning it? For computers which are disconnected from the network?

Comment: @mins on a home LAN it could be fine. OPs question is inherently about overcoming security mechanisms.

Comment: It's only "unsafe" in certain situations. Importantly, it's much less annoying in most situations than the default, which involves pointless copying of tokens on a local network.

Comment: yes, it disables the token auth. If you are running from docker(my use case), u can add that either in `.sh` script by editting it while image building or add like this with docker run command `start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.token=''`

Comment: Since I am running this on a remote server, how can I modify the printed URLs to point to the public ip address instead of 127.0.0.1? It's annoying to copy paste the token and append the address I write in the browser

Answer (score 31):

**How to avoid "Invalid credentials" by disabling jupyter Notebook Password & Token**

First open ***Anaconda Prompt***

1. Enter the command ***jupyter notebook --generate-config***

[image]

2. From jupyter directory ,edit the ***jupyter_notebook_config.py***

made changes into the following command

```
 c.NotebookApp.token = ''
 c.NotebookApp.password = u''
 c.NotebookApp.open_browser = True
 c.NotebookApp.ip = 'localhost'
```

Now launch the jupyter notebook from anaconda navigator *definitely the problem will be resolved as soon..*

Answer (score 22):

If you are trying to run from `docker` without password just use `CMD` like bellow:

```
CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--no-browser","--NotebookApp.token=''","--NotebookApp.password=''"]
```

Comment: yes, it is correct. We can also edit the `.sh` file, my case, custom-start.sh where i written like this `jupyter notebook  --allow-root --no-browser --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --NotebookApp.token='' --NotebookApp.password=''` and builded the jupiter notebook image

Comment: if anyone read above comment and wanna try that method, i explained it as an `answer `below

Answer (score 10):

Notebook 4.3.0 has enabled login security by default. The token to enter in the password field is printed in the output of the notebok server during startup (or can be included directly in the URL)

```
The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://0.0.0.0:8888/?token=f3e7fa23fb7e347ad05914368b625416b7a95a674dc078f7
```

See http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#server-security for more info, including disabling the feature.

However, this would not explain why you get the password prompt when running on one port but not on another

Comment: The cookies used are different on different ports, so you can be logged into a server on one port, but not on another. You can see the URLs with tokens of all running servers with `jupyter notebook list`.

Answer (score 6):

You can first create a jupyter config file with:

cd ~/.jupyter

jupyter notebook --generate-config
Then set the c.NotebookApp.token parameter to an empty string in the configuration file created

c.NotebookApp.token = ''

As mentioned in comment, Setting to an empty string disables authentication altogether, which is NOT RECOMMENDED.

Answer (score 5):

For me, the solutions described above was not applicable in Docker.

The following solution works like a charm on Linux:

**Details:**

- used image: `tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3-jupyter`
- password I configured: 'password'
- run Jupyter as a user (not root)

**Steps to start Jupyter in Docker with your pre-defined password:**

1. `export JUPYTER_TOKEN='password'`
2. `docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 -u $(id -u ${USER}):$(id -g ${USER}) -e JUPYTER_TOKEN=$JUPYTER_TOKEN -v /home/<user>/jupyter:/tf/ tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3-jupyter`
3. open http://localhost:8888 and use 'password' as your password
4. save password in ypur browser

For me, that is the easiest way to get rid of the annoying token authentication.

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to run from docker, there are different ways how u can disable authentication

If it is a simple `docker run` , we can try like this

```
docker run  -p 8888:8888 jupyter/minimal-notebook:57f8546c0386 start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.token=''
```

If we are building an image with `jupyter/minimal-notebook` as base image,

1. Create a custom-start.sh file

`jupyter notebook  --allow-root --no-browser --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --NotebookApp.token='' --NotebookApp.password=''`

2. Add the below lines in docker file

> COPY custom-start.sh /usr/local/bin/ RUN chmod +x
> /usr/local/bin/custom-start.sh CMD ["custom-start.sh"]

If it is a `docker-compose` file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  some_name:
    ports: ['8888:8888']  # docker run -p option
    image: jupyter/minimal-notebook:57f8546c0386
    command: start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.token=''
```

Answer (score 4):

The same issue occured on my machine since the last update of the jupyter-notebook package. After installing version

```
jupyter-notebook-4.3.0-1-any.pkg.tar.xz
```

it prompted me for a password I never set.
**Downgrading** to

```
jupyter-notebook-4.2.3-1-any.pkg.tar.xz
```

worked for me keeping the system a productive environment. Of course this **is just a fast patch**.

I also wondered where the password was set since I don't have an explicit config file in my `.jupyter`-folder. Setting up my own with

```
password_required=False
```

made no difference.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the token authentication by replacing the password inside `jupyter_notebook_config.json` by running `jupyter notebook password` on the  command line:

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>jupyter notebook list
http://localhost:8888/ :: C:\Users\320089053
http://localhost:8889/ :: C:\Users\320089053

(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>jupyter notebook list
Enter password:
Verify password:
[NotebookPasswordApp] Wrote hashed password to C:\Users\320089053\.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.json
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer is just to summarize what others said and give my two cents on the *token* thing discussed in the other answers.

What happened to the OP is a *password* for Jupyter instances is set -- somewhere -- in his environment. (He either set it directly or indirectly, it doesn't matter...in my case, I'm pretty sure I intentionally set it back in the days and then forgot about it.) The situation is *a jupyter notebook instance that can not be used because password is unknown/lost/forgot*.

There are two ways to do it permanently:

1. Change the password using Jupyter cli:

   ```sh
   $ jupyter notebook password
   ```

   > I tried to set an *empty* password here but apparently Jupyter does not allow that, something is generated for you if you don't fill it.
2. Edit your Jupyter config<sup>1</sup>. In particular, I wanted Jupyter to stop asking for a passwork/token:

   - I substituted the *NotebookApp-token* value I had in my `jupyter_notebook_config.json` for an **empty** string:

     ```sh
     $ cat ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json
     {
       "NotebookApp": {
         "token": ""
       }
     }
     ```

That's it. Now, whenever a new instance of `jupyter notebook` comes up you should *NOT* be asked for a password or token.

Answer (score 3):

First open Anaconda Prompt, then enter the command

`jupyter notebook --generate-config`

In my case the file was stored in the following directory (the Jupyter Notebook Server configuration directory)

```
C:\Users\<username>\.jupyter
```

In this directory, edit the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file to change the following configuration settings:

> c.NotebookApp.token = ''
> c.NotebookApp.password = u''
> c.NotebookApp.open_browser = True
> c.NotebookApp.ip = 'localhost'

Save the file, and then restart Jupyter Notebook Server to pick up the configuration change.

Answer (score 1):

Set a default password using below command

`jupyter notebook password`

Restart your notebook and enter the same password in the Browser

Answer (score 1):

There is jupyter_notebook_config.json file that is more priority than jupyter_notebook_config.py file, so you need to edit this json file, to find this directory, use this command

`jupyter notebook --generate-config`

this will create jupyter_notebook_config.py and show the location of that file, which will be in the same directory as jupyter_notebook_config.json, open jupyter_notebook_config.json and set the password value to "", this works on my side

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Many answers passing `Notebookapp.password` seem to be deprecated as of jupyter 7. This seems to work:

```bash
jupyter notebook --PasswordIdentityProvider.hashed_password=''
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `jupyter notebook password` to open jupyter & it asks to enter a new password.

The hashed password is updated in the `jupyter_notebook_config.json` file.