# jupyter notebook command can not run correctly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

After i install anaconda3 and open Jupyter,
it open by IE, i copy the url "http://localhost:8889/tree" and paste to Chrome, then it show this page
[page picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9gRS.png)
I follow instruction enter

```
jupyter notebook list
```

but it response this error

> File "", line 1
>      jupyter notebook list
>                     ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

why this error happen?

Answer (score 0):

Notebook 4.3.0 has enabled login security by default. The token to enter in the password field is printed in the output of the notebook server during startup (or can be included directly in the URL)

The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
http://0.0.0.0:8888/?token=f3e7fa23fb7e347ad05914368b625416b7a95a674dc078f7

See http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#server-security for more info, including disabling the feature.

However, this would not explain why you get the password prompt when running on one port but not on another.

same problem was asked
[How to disable password request for a Jupyter notebook session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41159797/how-to-disable-password-request-for-a-jupyter-notebook-session)