# Access the Jupyter Notebook by passing the credentials in URL or by using password less feature

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I am very much new to start work on Jupyter and I am trying to access the Jupyter Notebook with password less feature or to pass the credentials in url of Jupyter so that user will directly redirected to the notebook page instead of first hit the URL and then manually enter the Credentials .

For e.g. I have jupyter notebook available on my machine and currently it is accessible with url

```
https://localhost:8999
```

and after hit of URL it is landing on to the credential page on which I need to manually enter the required credentials.
But what I am trying ,to hit the URL https://localhost:8999 and it will land to the home screen which containing all the notebooks
What i was trying to do with the help of this link `[How to disable password request for a Jupyter notebook session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41159797/how-to-disable-password-request-for-a-jupyter-notebook-session)

But this not so much helpful because URL is not accessible and it is alywas generating the new token which tedious to manage

Is there any simpler way to make the Jupyter notebook accessible directly without entering any manual credentials

Comment: Would you be able to clarify the version of Jupyter, an what command you are currently using to launch the notebook? E.g. why it is running on port `8999` rather than the default. If you know the token, then you could go directly to `http://localhost:8999/?token=abc123` rather than manually typing it into the credentials page.

Comment: Using `https` is good practice if running a notebook server that others can connect to (so that someone monitoring their internet connection won't see the password), but when running locally it's unnecessary (as the traffic never leaves your computer). Do you want the URL to just be accessible to you, or are you trying to allow others to remotely access it without a password too? (possible, but not recommended!)

Comment: so the jupyter in installed in docker and the default port is mapped to 8999 port of the system.That is why I am doing https://localhost:8999 .Currently ,I have jupyterhub_config.py file with the help of which i am creating the URL with token

Comment: `jupyterhub`? Jupyter can be run locally on the user's computer, and is (relatively) simple to configure. JupyterHub is a whole other layer on top that spawns Jupyter notebooks for teams of people (but is well beyond me, sorry). If you need help with JupyterHub, you will need to update/repost your question with the `jupyterhub_config.py` file and tag with `jupyterhub`.