# Is it possible for another device to connect to jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, localhost

Is it possible for another device to connect to Jupyter on my current device? Without using jupyterhub

Like the way xender works offline.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answers for this question would be helpful:
[Why I can't access remote Jupyter Notebook server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848130/why-i-cant-access-remote-jupyter-notebook-server)

You need to set the Jupyter configuration file *jupyter_notebook_config.py* like this:

```
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*' # allow all origins
c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0' # allow all ip
```

Also, don't forget to modify your firewall setting, if any.

Comment: It doesn't work when i try to connect to the ip on another device. NB: There are two devices involved in this .