# Accessing Jupyter notebook on a remote server

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I am trying to use the Jupyter notebook from a remote server using the server's IP address and have followed the suggestions from this SO question:

[Why I can't access remote Jupyter Notebook server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848130/why-i-cant-access-remote-jupyter-notebook-server)

The following command has worked in all the server instances but I am facing issue with one particular instance:

```
jupyter notebook --ip xx.xx.xx.xx --port 8889 --allow-root
```

In this particular server instance, this throws the following error:

```
 File "/root/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 270, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 663, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1769, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1490, in init_webapp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 151, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 174, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

The issue seems to be with the use of IP address and not the port despite the following settings on jupyter_notebook_config.py

```
c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*'
c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access = True
```

I have looked at solutions on SO and Github and most of them are for localhost and not specific IP addresses.

Can someone point to what could be the issue? Thank you.