# Can't access jupyter notebook in docker

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I want to install jupyter notebook into my docker image. After installation and running it in container, I can't access it from my browser.

Here is my minimal setup:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.5
RUN pip install jupyterlab
EXPOSE 8888
CMD jupyter-lab --allow-root
```

commands

```sh
docker build -t my_image .
docker run -p 8888:8888 my_image
```

container output:

```
    To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-7-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/lab?token=e6b9a5dd573aabc52e6753e7b21f0daf6270e685055afa50
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=e6b9a5dd573aabc52e6753e7b21f0daf6270e685055afa50
```

I try to open any of these links, and get this message in browser:

```
This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default Jupyter is configured to listen only on localhost interface, you need to config it to listen on 0.0.0.0 (the container's localhost isn't your host localhost..)

change you `CMD` line in the Dockerfile to `CMD jupyter-lab notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8888 --allow-root`

or edit `jupyter_notebook_config.py` within the container/image:
change line starting with `c.NotebookApp.allow_origin` to `c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*'`
and change line starting with `c.NotebookApp.ip` to `c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'`

used this question for help: [Why I can't access remote Jupyter Notebook server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848130/why-i-cant-access-remote-jupyter-notebook-server)