# AWS Jupyter notebook can't find runnable browser - EC2 Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

Let me give the necessary context:

Security group details for Instance:

[image]

Jupyter Notebook Config File Snapshot:

[image]

When I run `jupyter notebook` this is what I get

[image]

And I cant connect to the Instance as I am getting this error:

[image]

Not sure what I am missing out or doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you set [allow_origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848130/why-i-cant-access-remote-jupyter-notebook-server)?

Answer (score 0):

You can run it in a headless mode, without browser:

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser
```

Then you can access it from your local workstation. Preferably over **ssh tunnel** for security reasons, rather then directly.

Comment: How do I access it from my local workstation?

Comment: @KaushikKaralgikar In your browsers you use: http://instance-url:8888, or http://instance-ip:8888. But this is not secure, best to use ssh tunnel for that.