# Jupyter seems to connect fine, but cannot access in a browser

Tags: server, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to open Jupyter notebook in a browser. Jupyter seems to have connected just fine:

```
[I 20:38:02.663 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/vmadmin/.jupyter
[I 20:38:02.663 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.2.0 is running at:
[I 20:38:02.663 NotebookApp] http://nameofVM:8888/
```

But when I plug in the URL given (`http://nameofVM:8888/`) the page doesn't load, with an error message just like when you try to visit a page where the site doesn't exist.

I've already tried all the steps from the solutions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848130/why-i-cant-access-remote-jupyter-notebook-server). I've also read through and tried troubleshooting with [the documentation](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/troubleshooting.html). I'm not sure how to fix this. Does anyone have any suggestions? I'd be grateful.

Notes:

- When I checked a list of all my kernels, I have one:

  `python3    /home/user/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3`
- I am using a Linux VM running Ubuntu 16.04.7