# How to correctly access to remote Jupyter Lab server (Gitpod) and how to provide security

Tags: security, jupyter, jupyter-lab, gitpod, jupyter-kernel

I'm working on a project, and one of the steps is to allow contributors to be able to use `Jupyter Lab` on the `Gitpod`. Also in our project, we assume that users can use `Jupyter Lab` on a compute cluster and connect to it from home. So basically our problem is related to accessing a remote `Jupyter Lab` server.

When I started testing this functionality, I noticed that we had a kernel connection problem (none of the used kernels can connect properly).

I started looking for information and found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848130/why-i-cant-access-remote-jupyter-notebook-server/43500232#43500232) and [here](https://github.com/gitpod-io/gitpod/issues/758) that we need to change config options in `jupyter_notebook_config.py`. So I changed default option which is

```
c.ServerApp.allow_origin = ' '
```

to

```
c.ServerApp.allow_origin = '*'
```

After that change all kernels are connected properly.
But I started to wonder about security.

Is it safe to do it this way? I know that `Jupyter Lab` requires a token to be able to connect to the server and maybe that's enough, but I'm not sure.

Comment: See discussion in https://github.com/gitpod-io/gitpod/issues/16306